# Awk if lower than 0

Tags: awk

```
awk -F, '$2>0 {print $1}' file.csv
```

This return nothing.

```
awk -F, '$2<0 {print $1}' file.csv
```

This returns everything.

What I want is if $2 has a value lower than 0, I want the name in $1.
Same for if higher than 0.

To sum up, I want to split my list in two; higher and lower than zero.

File.csv:

```
"" "log2FoldChange" "padj"
"AASS" 0.585822345291 0.0142249243232589
"ABCC3" -1.12579715427411 0.00503178459354681
```

Comment: 'everything' of what? Please include a sample of your input.

Comment: Your code seems correct from the requirement.  Input in column 2 doesn't seem to be in correct format.  Consider providing sample input

Comment: The complete file.txt is displayed in the first CMD, and nothing of file.txt in the second CMD.

Comment: We need to see the contents of file.csv, not just its name.

Comment: Ok, I just pasted the first 3 rows. Header, row one (>0) and row two (<0). I want the name "AASS" for >0 and "ABCC3" for <0.

Comment: The rows are not shown correctly.

Comment: your sample input is space-separated, not comma-separated.  Why do you have `-F,` on the `awk` command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have told awk to split its input lines on the character `,`, but your example input contains no `,` characters.  Your example input uses spaces to separate its input fields.  So `$1` is the entire input line, and `$2` is the empty string, which is always less than `0`.

Fix your input, or tell awk to split on spaces.

Also, if you are using GNU awk, you may want to read [“Splitting by Content” in the *GNU Awk User's Guide*](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Splitting-By-Content) if your content can contain spaces (or commas?) inside a quoted field.